# Identifying time in & time out in a column

Tags: php

I have a Library system for time in & out for the students. The students can go in when they want and go out when they want. This is how it works: There is a barcode on each student ID. They need to hover under the scanner every-time they pass the door, which automatically saves the Data.
Here is my code for saving.

```
<?php
$scan=$_GET["scan"];
include("connection/mysqlconnect.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM student where Barcode like('$scan%')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1)
    {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
        $crs_id = $row['course_id'];
}

$my_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+7 hours"));

$sql="insert into dtr 
(students_id,course_id,Date_Time)values('$id','$crs_id','$my_date')";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

The above code works perfectly.

But, I want to identify if it is in or out in a single column.

Below is my sample table. I want to add the In-Out Column.

```
Student_ID        Course_ID       Date_Time                 In-Out
  11                 4            2018-02-09 08:31:05         in
  22                 5            2018-02-09 09:35:09         in
  22                 5            2018-02-09 09:45:08         out
  11                 4            2018-02-09 10:01:05         out
  22                 5            2018-02-09 11:35:09         in
```

My problem is: I want to identify if the last hover is "in", in the column "In-Out" and the system will save the "out".

Comment: things for editing @Makyen

Comment: How can the system determine if a hover is an in or an out? Is there an actual deterministic way for the system to *know* that the student is going in or going out? With only one reading station, and no additional data, this is usually just a guess (it can be a reasonable guess, but it's just a guess).

Comment: its just in my mind actually. is there a way to check the data first before it save, its like checking the last data from a particular ID if it is an "in" or "out" then it will save the new data. and it is automatically saving the data so it means no buttons or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way would be to select the records from the dtr table for that student/course combination and just fetch the last one...

```
$sql="SELECT `In-out` as lastAccess FROM `dtr` where Student_ID = $id 
    order by Date_Time desc limit 1";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql);
$count2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);

$lastAccess = 'out';
if( $count2 == 1 )    {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $lastAccess = $row['lastAccess'];
}
$lastAccess = ( $lastAccess == 'out' )? 'in':'out';
```

This will go after the first SQL to check the student and before the insert.  The insert can then use $lastAccess.

Note that if a row in this table isn't found, the value of $lastAccess is 'out' (set prior to the test and therefore the bit which inverts this will set a new value of 'in' as it's the first time this student has used the system.

Comment: Thank you @Nigel, I will work on your code and try it out.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong @Nigel, but it only save the "in".

Comment: Can you check if it goes into the `if( $count2 == 1 )    {` bit. See if it matches a row from the query.

Comment: i don't know what you mean. but I followed your instruction above.

Comment: Can you put an `echo` or something in the code to see if it goes into the `if` statement.

Comment: it added the complete line in saving the data to database, like the student_id,course_id,date_time and the in-out. but in the in-out column all data are "in"

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest version of the code, it will help.

Comment: Can you try and run that SQL statement using something like phpmyadmin and see if it returns any rows. (The one I've added)

Comment: I run a few test, its not running. it only runs the code I made. it returns a row but in the in-out column it save the "in",

Answer (score 0):

Here @Nigel

```
<?php
$scan=$_GET["scan"];
include("connection/mysqlconnect.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM student where Barcode like('$scan%')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1)
    {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
        $crs_id = $row['course_id'];
}

$my_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+7 hours"));



$sql="SELECT `in-out` as lastAccess 
        FROM `dtr` 
        where student_id = $id 
        order by Date_Time desc
        limit 1";
                        $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
                        $count2=mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                        $lastAccess = 'out';
                        if( $count2 == 1 )    {
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                            $lastAccess = $row['lastAccess'];

                            // Check
                            echo "in-out=".$lastAccess.PHP_EOL;

                        }
                        $lastAccess = ( $lastAccess == 'out' )? 'in':'out';
                        // Check
                        echo "next in-out=".$lastAccess.PHP_EOL;


$sql="insert into dtr (students_id,course_id,Date_Time,in-out)values('$id','$crs_id','$my_date','$lastAccess')";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think its not going through the if statement cuz I put an error like changing the $result2 to $result5, $row to $row2 and mysqli to mysql and still saving the "in".

Comment: I've added a few `echo` statements to this code, can you see what that gives.

Comment: its not showing anything on me. maybe because of automation, i don't know. but theirs no error or anything. still save the same

Comment: Have you tried running this directly?  So not using any other app, just type the URL for this code in the address bar with `?scan=xxx` where xxx is a value which you know will match a record.

Comment: I have to go out, will be back in about 1.5 hours.

Comment: I've made a couple of changes to your code - on the insert statement, you need to have backticks round the column name in-out, and `mysqli_error()` needs the connection to be passed in.  I've tried this and it seems to work on my tests.

Comment: Just noticed that the `order by` in my statement should be descending, so I've changed that to `order by Date_Time desc`